# Send an Ajax request based entirely on the outcome of a first ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I am not amazing at jQuery, however I am building a system whereby a user selects from a static category which launches an Ajax request (specifically a .load ) which returns data in a second SELECT statement.

This works perfectly for my purposes. What I am having difficulty with is getting the selection of this second SELECT statement to run the second Ajax request. There is no output at all with the second request, it doesn't appear to fire.

Please let me know how I can improve my jQuery and how I can make the user choice on the second SELECT box populate the third SELECT box.

MY Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#squery").change(function(e) {

    SelectText = $("#squery").val();
    PassData = $("#pdata").html();
    if (SelectText == ""){
        $("#teamMailer").slideUp();
    }
    else {
        $("#teamMailer").load("mailerAjax.php", { SelectInput: SelectText, PermissionData: PassData });
        $("#teamMailer").slideDown();
    }
});

/**
THE BELOW DOES NOT APPEAR TO WORK OR FIRE AT ALL.
**/

$("#S_part2").change(function(e) {

    Part2Text = $("#S_part2").val();
    PassData = $("#pdata").html();
    if (Part2Text == ""){
        $("#teamMailer2").slideUp();
    }
    else {
        $("#teamMailer2").load("../includes/mailerAjax2.php", { SelectInput2: Part2Text, PermissionData: PassData  }, function( response, status, xhr ) {
            if ( status == "error" ) {
                var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
                 $( "#error" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
                 }
        });
        $("#teamMailer2").slideDown();
    }
});
});
```

Some notes:
The mailerAjax.php file contains the complete form SELECT function:

```
SELECT id="S_part2"
options
options
options
/SELECT
```

The output from the first Ajax is perfect but the second ajax doesn't seem to fire and there appears to be no return. not even an error.

my HTML:

```
<div class="...">Select Recipient(s):</div>
            <div class="...">
<select name="Target" tabindex="1" required id="squery">
                    <option value="" selected>Choose...</option>
                    <option value="I">Individuals...</option>
                    <option value="T">A Team...</option>
                    <option value="G">A Group...</option>
                                        </select>
</div>
        </div>


        <div class="..." id="teamMailer">

        </div>
        <div class="..." id="teamMailer2">

        </div>
```

So, 1) I like the neat and tidy use of .load function of jQuery, but do I need to use another function such as .post (I really want to avoid GET data transfer) ?

2) ignore this

3) I am aware that a basic solution *might* be to have the SELECT boxes (unpopulated) already in the base HTML, however it looks beautifully neat with the whole select box appearing only once it's populated.

So is there a way of getting the Ajax return for the third Select box from the ajax return of the second box?

Any guidance as too how to approach this, many thanks!

M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) `.load` is a GET request.

2) No.

3) Your problem is that you can't bind an element that doesn't exist. `S_part2` I assume is loaded from your first request, so you need to bind at a higher level and let event delegation handle it when the event bubbles up.

So instead of this:

```
$("#S_part2").change(function(e) { ...
```

Try this:

```
$("#teamMailer").on("change","#S_part2", function(e) { ...
```

This attaches the handler to your (I assume) parent div that does exist and adds a filter so that it will only execute when the original source of the event matches the id `S_part2`.

Comment: Thank you. I was myself confused with .load as firebug states its a GET request but the data is handled in PHP as $_POST['data'] (the GET alternative is empty), it works, but in an ideal situation I prefer POST over GET, but it's not too vital... 

RE: the handler -- thanks for the pointer on shaping the request, It seems so obvious now you've pointed it out, I'll go give it a try...

ps- my Q2) sorry that was a dumb Question :-/

Comment: Thank you Matt that's worked just as I wanted, cheers for the pointer!

Comment: @Martin: Not sure what your problem with GET vs POST is. By convention, this sounds like it *should* be a GET request. As for why it's showing up as `$_POST` on the PHP end, I don't know, but PHP is weird. [.load](https://api.jquery.com/load/) is a GET request and firebug confirms that.